# Finite Presentation of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, covering-spaces, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory

I have the group $\langle a,b \mid a^3b^3\rangle$ Now I send both $a$ and $b$ to the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. This gives a well-defined homomorphism from our group to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and I am asked to find a finite presentation of the kernel of this homomorphism. How do I generally tackle these kind of questions?

I know about covering spaces, fundamental groups of spaces, I understood I should take a cell complex and then find a cover corresponding to that subgroup, but I don't get how to do it so far.

Comment: You could use the Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm. You need to provide more context about your knowledge of the theory of group presentations.

Comment: I know about covering spaces, fundamental groups of spaces, I understood I should take a cell complex and then find a cover corresponding to that subgroup, but I don't get how to do it so far.

Comment: Ah, that's a different method, and I will leave someone else to help you with that.

Comment: Hint: Start with the wedge of two circles $X=S^1 \vee S^1$ and consider a homomorphism $h: \pi_1(X)\to Z/3$ sending each natural generator to the generator of $Z/3$. Can you identify the 3-fold cover of $X$ corresponding to the kernel of $h$? Nw, add some 2-cells...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491425) I get a presentation of the kernel:
$$\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\mid x_2x_3x_4\rangle$$
where
\begin{array}l
x_1:=a^3,\\
x_2:=ba^{-1},\\
x_3:=aba^{-2},\\
x_4:=a^2b\end{array}